# Displaying text file using table javafx

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, text-files, java.util.scanner

I have been trying to do this for a week now, I have created a java program using javafx and scenebuilder. I wanted to be able to open a text file and generate a table using the values of the text file.

**So far I have:**

- Created file opener
- Created an array that grabs the correct values from the text file

The issue I am having is linking the file selected to the array I have created, and then creating a dynamic table using the values from the array. I'm not sure where to start, to make this work.

Working file chooser: https://gyazo.com/884b215545a7beebedfe7e9bfab064ed
Scene builder table: https://gyazo.com/5637d10c7191710d24c2e2d42c53675e

**Text file**

```
john, smith, usa, California
sarah, parker, usa, Iowa
simon, davids, usa, Mississippi
```

**File opener code**

```
public class SampleController {

private Button btn1;



public void Button1Action(ActionEvent event) {
    {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters()
            .addAll(
                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("TXT files (*.TXT)", "*.TXT"),
                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("txt files (*.txt)", "*.txt"));

        File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (file != null) {
            try {
                Files.lines(file.toPath()).forEach(System.out::println);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JavaFXReadTextFile.class.getName())
                        .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }


}{





 }
```

**Array for text file**

```
public class tableValue {

public static Scanner value;


{


    try {

        value = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
        // code for number of lines start
        File file =new File("data.txt");

        if(file.exists()){

            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(fr);

            int linenumber = 0;

                while (lnr.readLine() != null){
                linenumber++;
                }

                lnr.close();

                // code for number of lines end

                String[][] valuezz = new String [linenumber][];

                for (int i = 0; i < linenumber; i++) {
                        String line = value.nextLine();
                        String [] oneRowValue = line.split(",");
                        animalzz[i] = new String[oneRowValue.length];
                        for(int j=0; j<oneRowAnimals.length; j++) {

                            // Here you are storing values
                            valuezz[i][j] = oneRowValue[j];

                        }
                }

                System.out.println(valuezz[2][3]);
                // Outputs Mississippi









        }else{
             System.out.println("File does not exists!");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {

        System.out.println("could not find file");

    }





}
```

Comment: Is the structure of the file predetermined (i.e. does it always have four columns, representing first name, last name, country, region)?

Comment: yeah its always going to be the same

Comment: So why not just define a model class and use the data from the file to create instances of it; most of the standard tutorials do this. ([This one](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part2/) is popular.)

Comment: So would I put the code for the file opener and array for text file, in the model class all together?

Comment: No, the model class should just be a model class, just like the one in the tutorial I linked.

Comment: I'm confused I understand the code from the tutorial but how am I supposed to get the data from the text file into the main class?

Comment: For each line in the text file, create an instance of the model class and add it to the table view's backing items.

Comment: Ok will do, thank you

Comment: BTW: There is no polite way of saying this: The code of the `tableValue` class is bad. You're loading your data in a initializer and never store the data anywhere. Furthermore you store the `Scanner` in some `static` field. You never access it anywhere else though, never close it and even if it was used somewhere else, it'd be at the end of the content. Also you check if the file exists after trying to open it with the scanner which would yield an exception for non-existing files. Also instead of reading the file twice you could simply use a list.

Comment: I recommend using a method to load the contents of the file. A suitable signature would be `public static List<String[]> readFile(File file) throws IOException`...